# Cell content not showing on UICollectionView

Tags: swift

I have been following a code-along on youtube which has some of the features that I need to use in an app I'm building. However, my cells in a subview of UICollectionView do not show up.

I have already tried messing with the parameters of the cells and the views but nothing seems to work.

In a separate class:

```
extension UIView{

func addConstraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...){

    var viewsDictionary = [String:UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
    }

    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}

extension UIColor {
static func rgb(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, a:CGFloat) -> UIColor{
    return UIColor(red: r/255, green: b/255, blue: g/255, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

In the ViewController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        setupMenuBar()
    }


    let menuBar: MenuBar = {
        let mb = MenuBar()
        return mb
    }()

    private func setupMenuBar() {
        view.addSubview(menuBar)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
        view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(60)]", views: menuBar)
    }
```

In the created class for views:

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(r: 230, g: 32, b: 31, a: 1) 
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()


    let cellId = "cellId"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        addSubview(collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
   }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        return cell
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I expect for the cells to show up on the menu bar, however the only thing that is appearing when I run the code is just the red bar, no blue cells.

Comment: set a breakpoint in the celForItemAt indexPath method. check that it s actually called and that the item size is correct and not 0.

Comment: `let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)` this `collectionView` has a `frame` with zero width and height.
You must provide a frame with width and height, such as `(frame: CGSize(x:0, y:0, width: 100, height: 100))`. Obiviously, adjust width and height as you want, maybe with super view values.

[CGSize zero](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize/1455512-zero)

Comment: Adjusting the frame value doesn't seem to help, the cells are still invisible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the frame of the collection view as that is handled by your use of constraints.  The problem is with this line:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewLayout()
```

From the documentation `UICollectionViewLayout` is:

> An abstract base class for generating layout information for a
>   collection view

So in of itself it does not provide proper layout information and you should use a subclass of it to provide the correct layout information.

One example of this is the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which allows you to layout the cells in a basic grid format.

If you replace the above line with this then you will see the cells:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

You can then modify the parameters that class provides or create your own subclass of UICollectionViewLayout with provides the details of the layout you require.

Comment: Thank you for the fix! Must have overlooked this part when I let xcode autocomplete

Comment: No worries glad I could help.